# Can I pass a content of a local file to Hadoop Pipes job

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I need to initialize objects in my mappers with information stored in a local text file. Is there any mechanism for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the file to HDFS and then add it to the distributed cache, making it available to the mapper to load from the working directory.

Uploading the local file to HDFS and placing it in the distributed cache is handled by the generic `-files` option

```
hadoop pipes -files localfile.txt <other pipes options>
```

Now to load the file in your mapper, just open a file (which you can assuming will be in the current working directory) of the same name (localfile.txt).

Comment: `Unrecognized option: -files`

Comment: @Inverse - good catch, put the pipes before the -files option

Answer (score 0):

Store the file locally on the client. Read it and serialize it and add it to the Job conf object.
In mapper and reducer's setup method, read the value from the conf object and deserialize it.

COnf object only stores string. Hence you need to convert it into String object while serializing it.